# Replacing characters in python - over-riding

Tags: python

I am having a bit of trouble here

I will give an example:

I am trying to replace 'F' with 'F - Fashion, O - Only' and 'FO' with 'F - Fashion, O - Only'. However, when I do this, I end up getting 'F - Fashion, O - Only - F - Fashion, O - Onlyashion, O - Only'

It seems like its over-riding the characters I don't want.

This is an example of the code I am using to go through the list of strings ['F', 'FO', 'FM'] etc

```
list_names = ['F', 'FO', 'FM'] #list
for index in range(len(list_names)):
    list_names[index] = list_names[index].replace("FM", 'F - Fashion, M - Multiple').replace('FO', 'F - Fashion, O - Only').replace('F', 'F - Fashion, O - Only')
    
print(list_names)
```

Comment: I think here you have a case where the chained `replace` statements used the replaced value from the previous `replace`s.

Comment: Do you mean  `'F'` -> `'F - Fashion'` instead of `'F'` -> `'F - Fashion, O - Only'` ?

Comment: 'F' and 'FO' should both be replaced with 'F- Fashion, O - Only'

Comment: The problem is that your replacement strings contain characters that are affected by a later substitution.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a dictionary to do this mapping.  The problem as you have posed it is not solvable.  If you are replacing "F" with a string that contains "F", then it should be no surprised that you'll get another replacement.

Comment: You're going to have to decide which priority these replacements are going to be; i.e. start with the most important / longest one, then when a replacement happens skip the other ones that are a substring of the one you inserted. Without knowing "what is the most important replacement", you can't really decide your original answer automagically.

Comment: How might I use dictionary for this?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
list_names = ['F', 'FO', 'FM']
replace_dict = {'F': 'F - Fashion, O - Only', 'FO': 'F - Fashion, O - Only', "FM": 'F - Fashion, M - Multiple'}
g = lambda x: replace_dict[x]
new_list = list(map(g, list_names))
```

results:

```
['F - Fashion, O - Only', 'F - Fashion, O - Only', 'F - Fashion, M - Multiple']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary instead:

```
mydict = {'F':'Fashion', 
        'O':'Only', 
        'FO': 'F - Fashion, O - Only'}

list_names = ['F', 'O', 'FO'] #list

for index in range(len(list_names)):
    list_names[index] = mydict[list_names[index]]
```

Something like that.

Comment: I think you should rename `dict` because the name is already reserved as a built-in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict